# Space between images grows on browser resize as the images shrink

Tags: html, css, image, scale, space

Hi i have a bunch of image links at the top of my page and they are causing me some grief.
The images resize of browser resize and screen resolution in media queries based on percent.
However the smaller the images get on browser resize or device screen res, the bigger the gap between each image gets.

Any ideas?

I tried putting `font-size:0;` but it didnt do anything

**CSS**:

```
.top_grow {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size:0;
    .top_grow img:hover {
        border: 2px solid #fff
    }
    .top_grow .text {
        font-size: 11px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        word-spacing: 1px;
    }
    .cats {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="top_grow">
            <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/hd-wii-wallpapers-mario-kart-super-mario-galaxy-2.htm">
                <img class="cats" src="test/super-mario-galaxy-hd-desktop-background_small1.jpg"></img>
                <div class="text">
                    Mario Galaxy`
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="top_grow">
        <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/free-music-wallpaper-big-music-wallpapers.htm">
            <img class="cats" src="test/Equalizer-music-wallpaper-music-bars-wallpapers_small1.jpg"></img>
            <div class="text">
                Music
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="top_grow">
        <a href="http://www.techagesite.com/cod7-call-of-duty-black-ops-wallpapers-7.htm">
            <img class="cats" src="test/cod7-call-of-duty-black-ops-background-7_small1.jpg"></img>
            <div class="text">
                Black Ops
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="top_grow">
        <a href="scooby-doo-wallpapers-character-backgrounds-coloring-pages-the-gang.htm">
            <img class="cats" src="test/scooby-doo-wallpaper-scary-cartoon-background-1024x768_small1.jpg"></img>
            <div class="text">
                Scooby Doo
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="top_grow">
        <a href="free-hd-neon-colours-desktop-wallpapers-download.htm">
            <img class="cats" src="test/bright-abtsract-glow-hd-wallpaper-1920x1080-hd_small1.jpg"></img>
            <div class="text">
                Neon Desktop
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="top_grow">
        <a href="funny-wallpaper-pics-quotes-photos-and-stuff.htm">
            <img class="cats" src="test/funny-wallpaper-pics-quotes-photos-and-stuff-cartoons_small.jpg"></img>
            <div class="text">
            Funny
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checkecked your code in Firefox and Chrome and the distance between images is always the same.
Anyway, your code doesn't looks to be valid - try to resolve validation errors - probably it will resolve your problem.
Also I don't think you can put one style definitions insite another.

Othe suggestion - try using display:block; with float:left; on .top_grow element.

Comment: It didnt work but thanks for the suggestion. Surprised no one else has commented.